# How to handle a set of objects in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am given the following data-file:

> stars.csv

```
Peter Piper,23,89.4,1.82
Polly Perkins,47,148.8,1.67
Griselda Gribble,92,48,1.45
Ivan Ng,19,59,2.0
Lucy Lovelorn,14,50,1.6
Leslie McWhatsit,70,59.2,1.65
```

I have been given a class definition (and some methods) as shown:

```
class Person:
    """Defines a Person class """
    def __init__(self, name, age, weight, height):
        """ Create a new Person object"""
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.weight = weight
        self.height = height

    def bmi(self):
        """ Return the body mass index of the person """
        return self.weight / (self.height * self.height)

    def status(self):
        """  status """
        bmi = self.bmi()
        if bmi < 18.5:
            status = "Underweight"
        elif 18.5 <= bmi < 25:
            status = "Normal"
        elif 25 <= bmi < 30:
            status = "Overweight"
        elif bmi >= 30:
            status = "Obese"
        return status

    def __str__(self):
        """ Output data """
        answer = "{0} ({1}) has a bmi of {2:.02f}. Their status is {3}."
        return answer.format(self.name, self.age, self.bmi(), self.status())
```

I was asked to a write a function read_stars(csv_filename) that takes as a parameter the name of a CSV file of person data and returns a list of Person objects, one for each line in the input file (and in the same order). The function should only require 7 - 10 lines.

Then I need to a create a new function filter_people(people, status) that takes a list of people and a "status" string and returns a new list containing just the people from the original list whose health status equals the status parameter.

> Here's what I came up with so far:

```
def read_stars(csv_filename):
    """reads file and sorts it then runs through a class"""
    items = []
    file = open(csv_filename, 'r')
    for row in file:
        name, age, weight, height = row.split(',')
        items.append(Person(name, int(age), float(weight), float(height)))
    file.close()
    return items
```

So far, so good. So, where am I stuck? In manipulating the filter_stars GLOBAL function. Is it possible to create a global function filter_stars(people, status) such that the output will be classified based on their bmi and status?

> Test code

```
bods = read_stars("stars.csv")
for status in ['Underweight', 'Normal', 'Overweight', 'Obese']:
    bods_with_status = filter_stars(bods, status)
    print("People who are {}:".format(status))
    for bod in bods_with_status:
        print(bod)
    print()
```

> Expected Output

```
People who are Underweight:
Ivan Ng (19) has a bmi of 14.75. Their status is Underweight.

People who are Normal:
Griselda Gribble (92) has a bmi of 22.83. Their status is Normal.
Lucy Lovelorn (14) has a bmi of 19.53. Their status is Normal.
Leslie McWhatsit (70) has a bmi of 21.74. Their status is Normal.

People who are Overweight:
Peter Piper (23) has a bmi of 26.99. Their status is Overweight.

People who are Obese:
Polly Perkins (47) has a bmi of 53.35. Their status is Obese.
```

I am finding it impossible to come up with a global function that can output as above.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. It takes 10 seconds to google how to filter a list, at which point all you have to do is come up with an appropriate filter condition. And you have that ready-made with the `status` method. Can you show us an attempt of yours to implement the `filter_stars` function?

Comment: I didn't even know that Python was capable of filtering a list. Do you mean like I can try using a for loop and 4 conditionals ?

Comment: python has a cvs module, you should use that to load your data. Are you asking stackoverflow to do your homework? Where is your non-functioning implementation?

Comment: Umm, yeah, I guess? A single condition would also suffice, though... And it really shouldn't be a surprise that python can filter a list... if it couldn't do that it'd be a worthless programming language...

Comment: @Aran, thank you for the sensible advise. I will try it out. Will update.

Comment: Please stop telling people to shove it. We get lots and lots of no-effort questions here every day, so it's only natural that we ask people to show us their failed attempts before we present them with a solution on a silver platter.

Comment: I apologise if my remark was uncalled for. But please understand that some of us are still beginners, who have a genuine desire to learn and seek advise from knowledgeable people. Some of us do put in effort before posting a question. A 'no-effort' question it may be for some, but for beginners it is not.

Answer (score -2):

> **Question**: ...create a new function `filter_people(people, status)` that takes a list of people and a `"status"` string and returns a new list containing just the people from the original list whose health status equals the status parameter.
>   ... output will be classified based on their bmi and status?

1. Define a function [8.6. Function definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#index-19)
2. Describe, your function’s formal parameter list and return value

   ```
   """
   arg1 = list of people 
   arg2 = "status" string 
   return => list of ?
   """
   ```
3. Define a `result variable` using one of the [Mutable Sequence Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)
4. Implement a traditional control flow construct with [8. Compound statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#)
5. Implement **"health status equals the status parameter"** with [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#index-1).
6. Append matching people to the `result variable` using a [Mutable Sequence Type Operation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)
7. Return the `result variable`

Edit your Question and show the code you worked out.
Comment if you get stuck with one of the above steps

Comment: Please note that I know how to google to find information on these topics. I participate in this community to get specific help with my coding. Not mere links to resources.